# What responsibility do I have when exporting knives to other country?

Tags: international, commerce, weapons

Suppose I'm an online shop owner who sells knives, but I don't have the means to learn the law of other countries.

Now suppose someone buys a knife from me, but the type of knife is illegal to own where he lives.  Can I be punished for shipping the product into his country? If yes, will I receive a fine, get a criminal record, or it's just simply the product could be seized by customs?  If it is seized by customs, do I have to refund the buyer?

Comment: take a look at the united state munitions list (USML)

Comment: @TTE I'm looking for what punishment should I expect to get when importing knifes to a place that's illegal, is it simply that the product will be taken by government, or I'll get something like criminal record?

Comment: All packages I get from other countries and send to other countries have a note that says something like "I am aware of the laws and regulations in the recieving country and confirm that there are no forbidden items in this package" and then they need to put a signature there. To keep it safe I would (at least in the beginning) only send to your own country. Also makes logistics lots easier.

Comment: @Andrew-at-TW to follow up to your comment: in my country you could get prosecuted for illegal weapon smuggling, which is quite harsh. But the question is if they would request assistance from the US or if you just should avoid my country from then on.